# How do I set a static MAC address for the default gateway on startup?

Tags: linux, debian, networking, mac-address, arp

I need to set the default gateway's MAC address statically.
I used the command:

```
arp -s <ip> <mac>
```

That works, but on reboot the entry is back to being dynamic.

I have tried:

1. Writing the same `arp -s <ip> <mac>` command inside a script, in the `/etc/network/if-up.d` directory

This seemed straightforward, but it didn't work. When rebooting, the arp entry is back to being dynamic.

2. Looking at the configuration inside `/etc/systemd/network/eth0.network`,

it contains:

```
[Match]
Name = eth0

[Network]
Description = Interface eth0 autoconfigured by PVE
Address = <ip>
Gateway = <ip>
DHCP = no
IPv6AcceptRA = false
```

I don't really know how I could change this configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to add this to your `/etc/systemd/network/eth0.network` file:

```
[Neighbor]
Address=<gateway IP>
LinkLayerAddress=<gateway MAC>
```

But the `Description = Interface eth0 autoconfigured by PVE` suggests this file may be managed by some other software, so it is possible any changes to it may be overwritten. Is this a virtual machine under Proxmox Virtual Environment?

A script in `/etc/network/if-up.d` would apply if you used a classic Debian `ifupdown` package to manage your network interfaces. But it seems you are (or Proxmox is) using plain `systemd-networkd` instead.

I don't know about Proxmox; anyone reading this, feel free to comment or write an answer of your own if you have a better Proxmox-compatible way to configure a static MAC address for a neighboring host persistently.

If there is no better way, you could of course define a custom service to run after regular network set-up, which would execute the required `arp -s` command.

Such a service definition might look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description = Set gateway MAC address statically
After = network.target network-online.target
Wants = network-online.target

[Service]
Type = oneshot
RemainAfterExit = yes
ExecStart = /usr/sbin/arp -s <gateway IP> <gateway MAC>
# Alternative command to set gateway MAC without the legacy arp command:
# ExecStart = /sbin/ip neigh add <gateway IP> lladdr <gateway MAC> nud permanent router

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

You might place it to e.g. `/etc/systemd/system/gatewayMAC.service`.

Comment: This is indeed a virtual machine with some external configuration going on. I will try it with the [Neighbor] things and apparently I can make a .pve-ignore. + file name to prevent it from being overwritten. I will get back after trying this

Comment: Yes! It worked! I added the [Neighbor] lines you wrote, and made a ".pve-ignore.eth0.network" file (empty) in the same directory so the Proxmox VE wouldn't overwrite it. I rebooted the system multiple times and the arp entry always has the CM flag.

Comment: I didn't try the other solutions you proposed yet but this seems like the most clean way of doing it for now. Thanks!